# How can I find the IP Addresses that devices connected to my phone's BT-PAN has issued

Tags: android, bluetooth, ip, dhcp

I am on Android 8.0.0 and have devices connected to a BT-PAN network my phone is hosting.

I would like to simply identify all IP Addresses that my phone has issued to BT-PAN DHCP clients. Can somebody either point me at an app which will list this, or perhaps an Android API Call which will give me this information.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [HE.NET network tools](https://networktools.he.net/). It allows you to do a ping sweep across an IP address range, like 192.168.44.0/24 and lists the clients that respond.